# File size certificate limitations for setting up Saml Single Sign on

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, certificates

I am having trouble loading a certificate (base64 encoded).  See the picture below.

When I load it, it has the following errors:  "Error:  Certificate file too large".

Are there any known limitations one file size?  I had also have had issues uploading DER encoded file, as well, which would be slightly smaller in size.

[image: Sales Force Dot Com Error]

Regards,

Comment: How big (in bits) is the cert you are creating? I don't think SFDC supports more than 2048...

Comment: Yes, we run into issue and fixed by compressing things as well removing some extensions.

Answer (score 3):

It means the cert you're uploading is too large for the storage we've allocated on the backend.   Are you uploading a complete cert chain?   Do you have lots of extensions?

Comment: Yes, we did at the time.  I believe we handled it by compressing it.  It seemed as if some included all possible extensions before the provided the cert to us.